# Ubuntu 18.04 lost the battery icon

Tags: indicator, battery, gnome-shell, gnome-tweak-tool

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 since it was released.

I installed GNOME Tweak Tool to show the battery icon. Today the icon was lost. But in GNOME Tweak Tool the battery percentage configuration is "ON".

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

accidentally, im just not properly insert the battery rightly on the place